# Ho to get the HTTP input field value and use it to do some tests using c:if

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

I'm having a Spring MVC application here. When menu page is opened i'm putting two model attributes: menuList and orderList. menuList is filled with infos from database and orderList is empty list that i want to be full-filled when the client is going to submit the dynamic form. I know how to bind all the products from the menu in the order list but that would be waste... of many things. What i need to do is to check if the value or length of the dynamically appended input field "pieces", next to each and every product, is greater than 0. How can i do that?

```
<c:url value="/menu/order" var="orderPath"/>
<form:form action="${orderPath}" method="POST" modelAttribute="orderList">
    <table>
        <tr>                    
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Calories</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Pieces</th>
        </tr>

        <c:set var="index" value="0" scope="page" />

        <c:forEach items="${menuList}" var="menu" varStatus="i">
            <tr>                    
                <td>${menu.name}</td>
                <td>${menu.code}</td>
                <td>${menu.price}</td>
                <td>${menu.description}</td>
                <td>${menu.calories}</td>
                <td><img src="<c:url value="/images/${menu.image}" />" alt="" width=120></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="pieces"></td>

                <!-- i need to take the "pieces" input field value here and check it if,                     
                 lets say, the length is greater than 0 (or the value is greater than 0)
                 and to make data binding only in those situations
                 I saw something like <c:if test="${param.pieces}>0"> but that's not working
                 or maybe i'm doing some kind of mistake, i don't know
                -->

                 <!--start: this code should be executed if the condition is evaluated to true -->
                    <form:hidden path="orderList[${index}].orderID"/>
                    <form:hidden path="orderList[${index}].menuID" value="${menu.menuID}"/>
                    <form:hidden path="orderList[${index}].pieces" value="**value-of-pieces-input-field**"/>
                    <c:set var="index" value="${index + 1}" scope="page" />
                 <!--end -->
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Make an order"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>        
</form:form>
```

Comment: JSTL functions may help -  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalg.html

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 1):

You're close.

```
<c:if test="${param.pieces > 0 }">
    <form:hidden path=.../>
</c:if>
```